# How to compare object based on key and value and remove from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular8

I have below  data in const rows.

```
 const rows = {
      "selected_parameter_value": [
        {
          "parameter_value": "a",
          "label_value": "a"
        },
        {
          "parameter_value": "d",
          "label_value": "d"
        }
      ]
    };
```

I want to compare each and every object of
const rows.selected_parameter_value with parameter_value
and label_value from this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value.

And delete those objects from  this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value which are not present in const rows.selected_parameter_value

**For example -**

In the **const rows.selected_parameter_value**, only a and d object are present, b and c are not present.

So remove object whose parameter and label values are b and c from this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value.

```
  this.selectedParameterContext = {
          'records': [
            {
              'selected_parameter_value': [{
                'parameter_value': 'a',
                'label_value': 'a'
              },
              {
                'parameter_value': 'b',
                'label_value': 'b',
              }]
            },
            {
              'selected_parameter_value': [{
                'parameter_value': 'c',
                'label_value': 'c'
              },
              {
                'parameter_value': 'd',
                'label_value': 'd',
              }]
            }]
        };


    **Expected Output -**

    this.selectedParameterContext = {
  'records': [
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [{
        'parameter_value': 'a',
        'label_value': 'a'
      }]
    },
    {
      'selected_parameter_value': [
        {
          'parameter_value': 'd',
          'label_value': 'd',
        }]
    }]
};
```

I tried below code

```
deleteContextData(rows ) { 
    const paramArray = rows.selected_parameter_value;
    const newArrayData = this.selectedParameterContext.records[0].selected_parameter_value;
    const removeMatchingData = (paramArray, toCompareWith) => {
      return paramArray.filter(({ label_value }) => !toCompareWith.some(compareObj => compareObj.label_value === label_value));
    }
    console.log(removeMatchingData(paramArray, newArrayData),"newarray");
}
```

Comment: In the final output you want `a` & `d` or only `d` from the context or only `a` from data?

Comment: In this.selectedParameterContext, right now two objects, In first object i want to keep a and d.
and in second object i want d only, bcz a is not avlbl in second object

Comment: Need to keep only those object which are avlbl in rows.selected_parameter_value remaining all objects need to remove from this.selectedParameterContext

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: Hi i have edited my question, plz review again.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data/source using `Array.filter` by comparing each object by matching object with the same `key-value` present in the comparing/target array and return only the ones which are not matching in the source array.

```js
let data = [{label_value: 'a', parameter_value: 'a'}, {label_value: 'b', parameter_value: 'b'}, {label_value: 'c', parameter_value: 'c'}, {label_value: 'd', parameter_value: 'd'}]
let contextData = [{label_value: 'b', parameter_value: 'b'}, {label_value: 'c', parameter_value: 'c'}];

const removeMatchingData = (data, toCompareWith) => {
  return data.filter(({ label_value }) => !toCompareWith.some(compareObj => compareObj.label_value === label_value));
}

console.log(removeMatchingData(data, contextData));

contextData = [{label_value: 'b', parameter_value: 'b'}, {label_value: 'c', parameter_value: 'c'}, {label_value: 'e', parameter_value: 'e'}];

console.log(removeMatchingData(contextData, data));
```

Comment: I have edited my question with example, plz review once again. it will more clear now.